# Software to evaluate Python code in a static web page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-development, python, programming

I am making a Github Pages site (static only, no server side code, JavaScript/JQuery is OK) on learning Python 3 code. I would like a way to:

- Evaluate the Python 3 code the user gives in an `<input>` or something similar.
- Print output, including error messages, to a `<pre><code>` or something similar.
- Assign output, including error messages, to a JavaScript variable or something similar in order to use it in a validation function (written in JavaScript/jQuery).
- Is portable enough to use on a Github Pages static web site.

Is there a library/software that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

[Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org) is a Python interpretor in JavaScript:

> Skulpt is an entirely in-browser implementation of Python.
>   No preprocessing, plugins, or server-side support required [...].

It is for Python 2, but apparently it already mostly work with Python 3, if I understand correctly most [Python 3 unit tests](https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/pull/688) are passing. I have not tested though.

Demos are available on their website, it is rather impressive.

Skulpt seems to load faster than the similar project [PyPy.js](http://pypyjs.org/), and has more Github stars.

- License: MIT (open source)
- Source code: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt

Apparently some online Python programming courses like Coursera use it, and so does Trinket.io:

[image]

Comment: I'll check it out when I get home today. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this work with Python 3? On Github, it says Python 2.x.

Comment: @OldBunny2800: Added some info.